# Error Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ActiveDs'

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, filenotfoundexception

I'm doing some active directory work with c# and I'm getting this error on my page

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ActiveDs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=46db4b78e98e1c9d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It's having some issue with the ActiveDS reference that was added
I'm on a 64-bit machine and the server it runs on is also x64

I added the ActiveDS reference so I could do something like this

```
newRoleGroup.Properties["groupType"].Value = ActiveDs.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL_GROUP;
```

So my question is, why can't it load the ActiveDs reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be far better off not taking the reference to the COM library and instead just declaring the proper constants in your code e.g.:

```
enum  ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM {
  public long ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP = 0x00000002,
  public long ADS_GROUP_TYPE_DOMAIN_LOCAL_GROUP   = 0x00000004,
  public long ADS_GROUP_TYPE_LOCAL_GROUP          = 0x00000004,
  public long ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL_GROUP      = 0x00000008,
  public long ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED     = 0x80000000
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

> 1) Copy the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ActiveDs.dll and its respective
>   ActiveDs.tlb file to a folder within your solution; call it an
>   External Reference folder
>
> 2) Remove the reference to ActiveDs in your project
>
> 3) Add a new reference, but this time instead of picking the COM
>   version, pick the TLB instead.  Visual Studio will create the Intero
>   wrapper for you.

Comment: Tried that... why would I do that if the server is running 64-bit?

Comment: Some older components that were designed for 32-bit environments don't work in 64-bit. I've run into that problem a few times before, just not with that component.

Comment: Is VS creating the interop DLL? Copy the DLL to your BIN folder, and drop and readd the reference with Copy Local set to true. After readding the reference, make sure that both the DLL and the Interop DLL are present in the BIN folder, and try again.

Comment: The Interop DLL is in bin\Release - should I make the copy of the DLL in that same place or above it, just in bin

Comment: Try putting them in the same folder together.

Answer (score -2):

I created an enum similar to Brian Desmond's answer:

```
private enum GroupType : uint
{
    UniversalGroup = 0x8,
    DomainLocalGroup = 0x4,
    GlobalGroup = 0x2,
    SecurityGroup = 0x80000000
}
```

and checked for both the universal group and security group like this:

```
private const int UniversalSecurityGroup = unchecked((int)(GroupType.UniversalGroup | GroupType.SecurityGroup));
```

Comment: You just did as @BrianDesmond said. You should have accepted his answer. -1